# Outdated SQL data after Post Request In NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following functions, one retrieve all table content `ConnectToDB()`, and the other INSERT a single value `InsertIntoTable()`. The Post request is handled in a way that `ConnectToDB()` is being called after I receive the `InsertIntoTable()` promise.

```
var express = require('express')
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express()
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.json())


function connectToDB()
{

    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: "*****",
      database: "heroes"
    });
    
    let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {

          con.query("SELECT id, name FROM heroes", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            myResolve(JSON.stringify(result));

          });
    
    });
    
    con.release;
    
    return myPromise;
}

function InsertIntoTable(obj)
{
    
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: "******",
      database: "heroes"
    });
    
    let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {

          con.query("INSERT INTO heroes (id,name) VALUES ("+obj.id+","+"'"+obj.name+"')", function (err, result, fields){
            if (err) myReject(err)
            else{
                console.log(result);
                myResolve(JSON.stringify(result));
            }

          });
    
    });
    
    con.release;
    
    return myPromise;
    
}


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    connectToDB().then(result => res.end(result));
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  console.log(req.body);
  InsertIntoTable(req.body).then(connectToDB().then(result => res.end(result)));
  

})

app.listen(8081,function(){
    console.log("server is listening...")
})
```

Nonetheless, the records received back from the post-call don't reflect the newly inserted value I just created.

Why the records are outdated? Is the `.then()` doesn't wait for the promise to be returned?

It's important to note that if I intiate a new `Get` call after the `Post` action, the records returned - are up to date.

Comment: Not sure what `con.release` is, I guess you're closing the database connection? But you're doing this just before querying the DB? If that's the case, of course it can't work

Comment: @Jeremy Thille The SQL operation works, but the data is outdated (in regard to the very last operation the post call intiated). In any case, I create a new connection at the beginning of each function. So as far as I understand I reopen them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are not waiting for the insert to finish before retrieving the records.

Here you are providing a function to "then", so that function is executed when connectToDB is resolved.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    connectToDB().then(result => res.end(result));
})
```

You need to provide a function to "then()", otherwise it will be executed immediatelly.

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  console.log(req.body);
  // old line. then is expecting a function but you are just returning data instead
  // InsertIntoTable(req.body).then(connectToDB().then(result => res.end(result)));
  // waiting for the result of the first promise
  InsertIntoTable(req.body)
     .then(() => {
        // here we are inside a function waiting for the first promise to be resolved
        return connectToDB().then(result => res.end(result))
      });
});
```

A little better "structured" approach:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      console.log(req.body);
      InsertIntoTable(req.body)
         .then(() => connectToDB())
         .then(result => res.end(result))
         .catch(err => {
            // handle you errors here
         })
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems to work. But why passing a function that will call connectToDB() making .then() wait for the promise to be resolved while calling connectToDB() directly won't make .then() wait for it ?

Comment: Then expects a callback function. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then